# Should questions that straddle web/desktop applications be migrated to SU?

Tags: discussion, migration

Saw this question

- [Is there a way to have a tweet/twitter marquee style ticker for chrome or windows?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44935/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-tweet-twitter-marquee-style-ticker-for-chrome-or-wind)

and was wondering if a question, such as this, that is looking for either/or a web extension *or* a desktop application as a solution should be migrated to [Super User](http://superuser.com)?

Would "best practice" be to isolate the web application part of the question if it's going to be asked on this SE?

Comment: I just saw that it was migrated- so I'm guessing the answer was yes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of those in-between places where it goes both ways really - since our FAQ mentions:

> If your question generally covers … Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)

then it's OK for us. While [Super User](https://superuser.com/) does indeed accept questions on Web browsers / desktop applications, provided they aren't product recommendations.

I've migrated to Super User - and in general, Web Apps deals more with how do I get x done in web apps y(with the addition of using extension) - but Super User focuses more on getting things done with the browser/extension, regardless of the web app.

Comment: Makes sense - just trying to be a conscientious flagger!